# editing the Excel.officeUI file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to add a button to the Quick Access Toolbar in Excel using a batch file?  Or do I need to edit the Excel.officeUI file in a VBA macro?

Comment: Create an Excel add-in (.xlam) which will contain the UI button and code and distribute this. Each user will only have to add it though Options >>> Add-Ins.

Comment: ***Welcome to [so]!***  That's a lot of writing with no examples.. Questions are more likely to get good answers if they are **short and to-the-point**.  (See "[ask]" and also "[mcve]".)  You can always [edit] your questions to clarify.

Comment: If I understand properly after scanning your question, **is *this* the main main point of your question**? :  `my attempts at saving it as a text file so far have led to quotes being added into the file, and any quotes already there becoming double quotes.`

Comment: The .xlam is an interesting thought, but I am trying to find a way to avoid having too many steps for the end-user

Comment: Installing an add-in is one step. No janky batch files. By far the easiest.